# How can i get next date using NSDate?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS and finding Tomorrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681989/ios-and-finding-tomorrow)

How can i get next date using NSDate. Please send me the solution.

Comment: You should mark one of the answers below correct if you feel it answers your question.

Answer (score 58):

In the following, yourDate represents your input NSDate; nextDate represents the next day.

```
// start by retrieving day, weekday, month and year components for yourDate
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:yourDate];
    NSInteger theDay = [todayComponents day];
    NSInteger theMonth = [todayComponents month];
    NSInteger theYear = [todayComponents year];

    // now build a NSDate object for yourDate using these components
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setDay:theDay]; 
    [components setMonth:theMonth]; 
    [components setYear:theYear];
    NSDate *thisDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
    [components release];

    // now build a NSDate object for the next day
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setDay:1];
    NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:thisDate options:0];
    [offsetComponents release];
    [gregorian release];
```

Comment: Hi, 
Yeah this code's working
Thanks a lot,

Do you have any idea about how to get previous day(yesterday)?

Comment: Changing [offsetComponents setDay:1] to be setDay:-1 results in subtracting a day instead of adding

Comment: This also works when the next date moves from daylight savings to standard time. Try moving from 2011-11-06. Thanks @unforgiven.

Comment: This code should crash because you are releasing components twice.

Answer (score 34):

```
NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Much more easiest way..

Comment: This can give incorrect results when there is a Daylight Savings Time change in the range of dates.

Comment: Also when there is a leap second.

Comment: This is not valid.. This will give date with same time after 24 hours.

Comment: Also breaks if the user travels between time zones.

Comment: It does not take care of the leap second as well. Hence it will break.

Comment: I take the points above but in some cases, e.g. when you just want a date in the future for testing, this is a simple solution.

Answer (score 33):

what about this methods ?

http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/05/adding-days-to-nsdate/

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = 50;  // or 60 :-)

// set up date components
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setDay:daysToAdd];

// create a calendar
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

NSDate *newDate2 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];
NSLog(@"Clean: %@", newDate2);
```

Comment: **Much** better solution than the most upvoted in this topic

Comment: Works like a breeze!

Comment: also useful `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`

Answer (score 2):

I guess this method works just fine for me.

```
NSString *zajtra = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];
```

Comment: This can cause issues when traversing day boundaries when accounting for DST.

Comment: Ditto, This can give incorrect results when there is a Daylight Savings Time change in the range of dates.

Comment: Will not do what you expect if there is a leap second.

Comment: Why does your `- [NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:]` return a `NSString`?

Answer (score 0):

//Add the below code to init method or viewDidload

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date]  forKey:@"Date"];
```

//Add this code where you wanna retrieve next or previous dates

```
NSDate *tomorrow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Date"];
NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;    
NSDate *date = [tomorrow addTimeInterval:secondsPerDay]; //Change NSDate *date = [tomorrow addTimeInterval:-secondsPerDay]; for yesterday
tomorrow = date;
[self setDate:tomorrow];
dateTextField.text = [self getDate];        
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tomorrow  forKey:@"Date"];
```

Comment: Cave: Repeatedly adding secondsPerDay (24 * 60 * 60) with addTimeInterval to an NSDate is done while observing daylight saving time. Adding 24 hours on a day when you enter or leave daylight savin time skews the time of day by +/- 1 hour.