# Get all dates (not days) between two NSDates

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdate

How can I get all the dates that come in between 2 dates?

For example:
Start date = 2011/01/25
End date = 2011/02/03

Comment: What do you mean by dates, and not days?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of days between two NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)

Comment: @JoshCaswell the subject said "Not days"  He want a listing of dates.

Comment: @Black Frog: But imMobile has not bothered to indicate _at what interval_. `NSTimeInterval` is a `double`, with millisecond resolution. There are literally millions of "dates" in between any two.

Comment: Yes, each millisecond is a different date in "Time & Space" but I believe he wants each day as 24 hour period.

Answer (score 2):

1) Find the no of days between two dates. Then,

```
for(i=0;i<noofdays;i++)
{
//Find the next date
//add to the array
}
```

[To find number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates/4739550#4739550)

[To find next date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081689/how-can-i-get-next-date-using-nsdate/1081711#1081711)

Answer (score 2):

`NSCalendarUnit` serves for defining the step between the dates & taking care of the dates being normalized.

**iOS 8 API, Swift 2.0**

```
    func generateDates(calendarUnit: NSCalendarUnit, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> [NSDate] {

            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let normalizedStartDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(startDate)
            let normalizedEndDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(endDate)

            var dates = [normalizedStartDate]
            var currentDate = normalizedStartDate

            repeat {

                currentDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(calendarUnit, value: 1, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchNextTime)!
                dates.append(currentDate)

            } while !calendar.isDate(currentDate, inSameDayAsDate: normalizedEndDate)

            return dates
    }
```

Comment: thanks. i'm using an objective-c version of this to complete my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To find all days between two NSDates:

```
- (void)cerateDaysArray{
    _daysArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendaralloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSDate *startDate = [_minDate copy];
    NSDateComponents *deltaDays = [NSDateComponents new];
    [deltaDays setDay:1];
    [_daysArray addObject:startDate];
    while ([startDate compare:_maxDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
       startDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:deltaDays toDate:startDate options:0];
       [_daysArray addObject:startDate];
   }
}
```