# How can I generate every date between two dates to a given granularity?

Tags: swift

How can I generate every date between two dates to a given granularity?

I want to make this extension pad an array of Dates, which all must be at 00m, 15m, 30m, or 45m, so that there are no gaps. Optionally, setting a start and an end date, that were not in the original set (so you can have leading and trailing dates).

```
extension TimeSeries {
    var earliest: Date? {
        return timeSeries.map { $0.date }.min()
    }
    var latest: Date? {
        return timeSeries.map { $0.date }.max()

    }
    func pad (to repletion: Int, _ component: Calendar.Component, from: Date? = nil, to: Date? = nil) {
        guard let start = from ?? self.earliest else {
            print("no start date given and none available")
            return
        }
        guard let end = to ?? self.latest else {
            print("no end date given and none available")
            return
        }

        // magic happens here...
    }
}
```

Specifically, given:

```
[ Date/* 2018-01-16 01:15:00 */, Date/* 2018-01-16 01:45:00 */]
```

I want the array to become:

```
[ Date/* 2018-01-16 01:15:00 */,  Date/* 2018-01-16 01:30:00 */, Date/* 2018-01-16 01:45:00 */]
```

And if it was called like `ts.pad(to: 15, .minutes, from: Date/* 2018-01-16 01:00:00 */, to: Date/* 2018-01-16 02:00:00 */ )`

I want the array to become:

```
[ Date/* 2018-01-16 01:00:00 */, Date/* 2018-01-16 01:15:00 */,  Date/* 2018-01-16 01:30:00 */, Date/* 2018-01-16 01:45:00 */, Date/* 2018-01-16 02:00:00 */]
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601583/get-weekdays-within-a-month/35603441#35603441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic could be something like this. Create array with start date as first element. Then append dates with added components to last date until new date should be greater than end date

```
func pad(to repletion: Int, _ component: Calendar.Component, from: Date? = nil, to: Date? = nil) {

    guard let start = from ?? self.earliest, let end = to ?? self.latest else {
        print("no date given and none available")
        return
    }

    var components = DateComponents()
    components.setValue(repletion, for: component)
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    var dates = [start] // results

    while start < end {
        if let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: dates.last!), 
           newDate <= end {
            dates.append(newDate)
        } else { break }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variant, assuming period is given by `start` and `end` dates

```
let quarter: TimeInterval = 15 * 60
let dateInterval = DateInterval(start: start, end: end)

var date = start
var result = [Date]()
while dateInterval.contains(date) {
    result.append(date)
    date = date.addingTimeInterval(quarter)
}
```

Comment: `date = date.addingTimeInterval(quarter)` can be shortened to `date += quarter`