# Objective C - get the following day from today (tomorrow)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can I check to see if a date is inherently TOMORROW?

I don't want to add hours or anything to a date like today, because if today is already `22:59`, adding too much would go over to the day after, and adding too little if the time is `12:00` would miss tomorrow.

How can I check two `NSDate`s and ensure that one is the equivalent of tomorrow for the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get next date using NSDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081689/how-can-i-get-next-date-using-nsdate)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can extract day/month/year components from the date representing today, ignoring the hour/minutes/seconds components, add one day, and rebuild a date corresponding to tomorrow.

So imagine you want to add exactly one day to the current date (including keeping hours/minutes/seconds information the same as the "now" date), you could add a timeInterval of 24*60*60 seconds to "now" using `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow`, but it is better (and DST-proof etc) to do it this way using `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSDateComponents* deltaComps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[deltaComps setDay:1];
NSDate* tomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:deltaComps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

But **if you want to generate the date corresponding to tomorrow at midnight**, you could instead just retrieve the month/day/year components of the date representing now, **without hours/min/secs part**, and add 1 day, then rebuild a date:

```
// Decompose the date corresponding to "now" into Year+Month+Day components
NSUInteger units = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];
// Add one day
comps.day = comps.day + 1; // no worries: even if it is the end of the month it will wrap to the next month, see doc
// Recompose a new date, without any time information (so this will be at midnight)
NSDate *tomorrowMidnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```

P.S.: You can read really useful advice and stuff about date concepts in the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i), especially [here about date components](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470).

Comment: How do you work around the fact that `NSCalendar`'s `dateFromComponents` returns `nullable` result? I know that tomorrow always exists and want to use this fact while coding. However, when I use this approach in Swift `tomorrowMidnight` _may_ be `nil`, at least that's what the compiler thinks.

Answer (score 7):

In iOS 8 there is a convenience method on `NSCalendar` called `isDateInTomorrow`.

Objective-C

```
NSDate *date;
BOOL isTomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInTomorrow:date];
```

Swift 3

```
let date: Date
let isTomorrow = Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(date)
```

Swift 2

```
let date: NSDate
let isTomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInTomorrow(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to leverage `NSCalendar`/`Calendar` to create tomorrow:

```
extension Calendar {
    var tomorrow: Date? {
        return date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startOfDay(for: Date()))
    }
}
```