# Adding a day to current date in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I saw this post: [iOS and finding Tomorrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681989/ios-and-finding-tomorrow).

The code provided is:

```
units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
// Add one day
comps.day = comps.day+1; // no worries: even if it is the end of the month it will wrap to the next month, see doc
// Recompose a new date, without any time information (so this will be at midnight)
NSDate* tomorrowMidnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Problem: I need to add a day to my current date so that for example, the difference between 21st Jun 2013 and 21st May 2013 is 1 month instead of 0 month.

The code I am using:

```
    NSDate *selectedDate = [picker2 date];
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [currCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:selectedDate toDate:[NSDate date]  options:0];
    DLog(@"%i",conversionInfo.month);
    DLog(@"%i",conversionInfo.day);
    conversionInfo.day +=1;
    DLog(@"%i",conversionInfo.day);
    DLog(@"%i",conversionInfo.month);
    int months = [conversionInfo month];
```

But when I tried to get the difference between 21st Jun 2013 and 21st May 2013 -> still returns me 0 month instead of 1 month.

Need some help on this.

Comment: If you just want to add a day to today, then do this : `NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];` This adds 24*60*60 seconds to given date and returns a new date.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. worked...add as an answer.. will mark it right..

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence in your question. Why should the difference between 21st Jun 2013 and 20th Jun 2013 be 1 month?

Comment: apologies on the last part.. typed wrongly...

Comment: @lakesh: OK. But the difference betwen 21st Jun 2013 and 21st May 2013 *gives* one month (I tested it). The problem could be that the two dates have different times. For example, the difference between "21st Jun 2013 00:00" and "21st May 2013 00:30" gives 30 days, 23 hours, 30 minutes and **0 months**. So perhaps you have to normalize the dates to midnight first.

Comment: Do you select only a day with the picker or day/hour/minute? What result do you expect if the current timestamp is "21st Jun 2013 10:00" and the selected date is "21st Aug 2013 9:00"? In other words, do you want to compute the difference to the *start of the current day* or the difference to the *current timestamp*?

Answer (score 15):

Form a date component with number of days you want to add to your original date. From the current calendar form the date by adding the this component to your original date.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
dateComponents.day = 1;
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents 
                                                               toDate: selectedDate 
                                                              options:0];
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a method I use:

```
+ (NSDate *)addDays:(NSInteger)days toDate:(NSDate *)originalDate {
    NSDateComponents *components= [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setDay:days];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:originalDate options:0];
}
```

With it, you can add as many days as you want. It also works with negative numbers, so you can subtract days.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and straight forward solution :

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDate *nextDate = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(24*3600)];
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: A day does not always have 86400 seconds. This calculation can give wrong results when transitioning to or from Daylight Savings Time. - (The same answer was already given and deleted later.)

Answer (score 2):

For swift googlers:

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: date, options: nil)!
```

Answer (score 0):

First Thing,you are assigning day instead of month to NSDateComponent.
Execute following code and find difference between inDate And newDate

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:inDate];
```

NSInteger monthFlag = 1;
components.month = minuteFlag;

```
// Retrieve date with increased days count
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                   dateByAddingComponents:components
                                   toDate:monthFlag
                                  options:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To add any number of any components to the date, for example: 2 days or 2 months, 1 year, do the following:

```
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: -1), to: date)! //this create date with previous month for date.
```

you can initialize `DateComponents` with anything:

```
public init(calendar: Calendar? = default, timeZone: TimeZone? = default, era: Int? = default, year: Int? = default, month: Int? = default, day: Int? = default, hour: Int? = default, minute: Int? = default, second: Int? = default, nanosecond: Int? = default, weekday: Int? = default, weekdayOrdinal: Int? = default, quarter: Int? = default, weekOfMonth: Int? = default, weekOfYear: Int? = default, yearForWeekOfYear: Int? = default)
```