# iOS 8 - get current date as DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: ios, date, nsdate

Can anybody give me some code how I get the date?

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendarcurrentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYearfromDate:[NSDatedate]]; 

NSString *day = [components day]; 
NSString *week = [components month]; 
NSString *year = [components year]; 

NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@",day,week,year];
```

^^ my code is not working :S

And is there a way that I can get the date of tomorrow, in 1 week and so on...

Thanks :)

Comment: Google "NSDateFormatter".

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: How is this question off topic? It's not asking anyone to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can either use a variation of your code that retrieves the numeric components using `NSCalendar` with the `components` method:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.%ld.%ld", (long)day, (long)month, (long)year];
```

Note, that's `components`, not `component`.

Or, better, you can use `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"d.M.yyyy";
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 11):

```
  NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date]; //Get todays date 
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date. 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; //Here we can set the format which we need 
    NSString *convertedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayDate];// Here convert date in NSString
NSLog("Today formatted date is %@",convertedDateString);
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You can get like this

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:Date())
print(dateString)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,set the different components unit:

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents * components =
                        [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger year = [components year];
```

if your want to get other days ,use this link 
 [calendar get other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081689/how-can-i-get-next-date-using-nsdate)